Are the answers of this questions all incorrect?
The question is:
What is the voltage of the AC voltage source if Ammeter 1 measure 0.6A and Ammeter 2 measures 0.8A?
R1 is 10 Ohms
R2 is 20 Ohms (See image below)

My solution is :
voltage at R1: (0.6A+0.8A)*10 Ohms
Votlage at R2: 0.6A*20 Ohms
Voltage of source: (0.6A+0.8A)10 Ohms + 0.6A20 Ohms= 26volts
No answer is 26 Volts.
Question is transalted above. Question 9)

The capacitor current is out of phase with the resistor current so you can't just add them. Use complex numbers.

yeea . I completely ignored that for some reason. Quire embarrassing

Please ask the actual question in the title. "Are the answers of this questions all incorrect?" is too generic.

This is your circuit.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The applied voltage, \$V_x\$, across \$C_1\$ and \$R_1\$ must be the same. It cannot be otherwise. But a resistor responds to that applied voltage differently than a capacitor does. In fact, the capacitor's current responds to the rate of change of the applied voltage while the resistor responds directly to the applied voltage.
This different way of responding to the same voltage means currents are exactly \$90^\circ\$ out of phase with each other. An inductor would be \$90^\circ\$ out of phase in one direction and a capacitor would be \$90^\circ\$ out of phase in the opposite direction. By convention, the inductor is assigned \$+90^\circ\$ and the capacitor is assigned \$-90^\circ\$. The resistor is laid out on the x-axis and the impedance of an inductor is on the positive part of the y-axis while the impedance of a capacitor is on the negative part of the y-axis. To keep capacitor and inductor impedance separated from resistance the imaginary value \$j\$ is used to indicate the y-axis.
Note: The magnitude is the length of the hypotenuse. So if one writes that the impedance is \$4+j3\$ then this means that the magnitude is \$\sqrt{4^2+3^2}=5\$. (But you still need to remember both parts, 4 and 3, that make up that magnitude.)
You know the magnitude of \$V_x\$ must be \$12\:\text{V}\$ because \$20\:\Omega\cdot 600\:\text{mA}=12\:\text{V}\$. So \$C_1=\frac{12\:\text{V}}{800\:\text{mA}}=-j15\:\Omega\$. The minus sign is applied because this is a capacitor and not an inductor; and \$j\$ is applied so that you keep the capacitor impedance separate (it's on the y-axis) from the idea of resistance in a resistor (which is on the x-axis.)
Now, you know that you have \$20\:\Omega\$ in parallel with \$-j15\:\Omega\$.
Keep also in mind that the currents are exactly \$90^\circ\$ out of phase with each other. You cannot directly add them as a simple sum but instead only in a root-mean-square method. So the combined current will be \$\sqrt{\left(600\:\text{mA}\right)^2+\left(800\:\text{mA}\right)^2}=1\:\text{A}\$.
The applied voltage must then be \$V_s=1\:\text{A}\cdot\left[10\:\Omega+\left(20\:\Omega\:\vert\vert\: {-j15}\:\Omega\right)\right]\$. I won't step through that calculation for you -- you should try your hand at it. But here is what my calculator says:
1*(10+(20|-15j))
17.2 - j9.6, 19.6977156 ∠ -29.1676134


Thanks for the answer. I got 22 volts becausei added the 12 volta directly with 10 volta instead of adding 12 volta to the phaser and then calculating the magnitude

You know the voltage at the top node from the current A1 and R2. You then can calculate the reactance of C from the current A2 and the voltage. I get -15j.
You can calculate the voltage just as you would with a resistive divider.
I get \$ U = 2\sqrt{97}\$ (volts).

what if i add the two current and assume one has a 90 degree delay?

Does it give you the correct answer?

no it does not i do not understadn why?

i get 22volts though

Well, I could have made a mistake that happens to agree with one of the answers or you could have. Why don't you run a SPICE simulation and see which it is?

@SpehroPefhany No, you have the right of it. (Don't need to simulate.) I think LEXOR just didn't follow the reason why you would arrive at -15 j (which makes sense) nor how to then combine things, after, I suspect.
